# Prompt When Unfinished in Filling Out Form in React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, material-ui, formik

I need to make a prompt like "Are you sure you want to leave? You have with unsaved changes." because if I accidentally close the Dialog, when I open it again, it will let make fill out the form again.

This prompt would prevent the Modal Dialog from being closed if they decided to close it with the text already inputted in the textfield or it will prevent the Modal Dialog from being closed too if they decided to redirect to different page.
The prompt has a Cancel and Ok button. Just like in the pic below.

[image]

I don't want to use the `<Prompt/>` of react-router-dom. Is there another way to do this?

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/formdialog-demo-material-ui-forked-z24hlp?file=/demo.js)

```
 <Form>
  <PromptIfDirty />
  <TextField
    autoFocus
    id="name"
    name="name"
    label="Enter Name"
    type="text"
    value={values.name}
    onChange={handleChange}
    onBlur={handleBlur}
    fullWidth
  />
  <Button
    type="submit"
    variant="contained"
    sx={{ marginTop: "2rem" }}
  >
    Submit
  </Button>
</Form>
```

Comment: Please provide more context about the wanted result. Do you want to prevent the user from navigating to another page? Or is your form inside a modal opened by React, and you want to prevent it from being closed?

Comment: @r0den. I already edited my question

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you move the condition

```
formik.dirty && formik.submitCount === 0
```

you currently use in your `PromptIfDirty` and move that to the `handleClose` callback. And if the condition is true, you could e.g. color the text input field red or display a label.

But ultimately you need to let your users close the form overlay if they want to actually close/cancel the input for a good UX.
You can do that either via a prompt or an explicit close button next to the "submit"

That close button can actually include a little prompt. So first click on the "close" button changes its state to "really?" and second click really closes the form.

Comment: Yes. good idea. anyway I have updated my question. Can you fork my codesandbox? You can apply your idea on the codesandbox